# Backing up proxy services and configurations in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have a WSO2 ESB 4.6 running some proxy services, my proxies have endpoints, sequences and other artifacts which are saved inline, in the registry and as standalone endpoints/sequences. I want to backup them. Is there any way that is suggested for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

If it is in registry use the [checkin client tool](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Check-in+Client) to backup. And take the backup of repository/server/deployment/synapse-config folder too

Comment: There isn't any thing that backup proxies one by one as a package?